# Flutter sfDataGrid Scroll is working in android touch screen

Tags: flutter, sfdatagrid

I am  using `sfDataGrid` within `SingleChildScrollView`
With this I am able to scroll with mouse wheel in a web browser.
When I try thins in android emulator, touch and slide scrolling is not working

If I remove `SingleChildScrollView`, I am getting out of area exception as I have more data than the screen can hold. Any suggestions on how to get vertical scroll working with touch and slide?

I am  using `sfDataGrid` within `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(children: [
            StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                stream: myStreamController.stream, // getMyClinics(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      ....
                      ....
                      return SfDataGrid(....)
                   }
                  }
                }
            )
           ])
```

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 0):

solved it with

```
Column(children: [
            Expanded(
                // add this
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: StreamBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
```